# Are the sets of executions of data-race free programs equal, when run on causal memory and on sequentially consistent memory respectively?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, dc.parallel-comp, dc.distributed-comp, concurrency

In the paper ["Causal Memory: Definitions, Implementations, and Programming (Distributed Computing [DC] 1995)"](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/6781/GIT-CC-93-55.pdf?sequence=1), the authors present a formal definition of causal memory, an abstraction of distributed shared memory that ensures that processes in a system agree on the relative ordering of operations that are *causally related*.

More interestingly, it is shown that data-race free (DRF, for short) programs, if written to run correctly on sequentially consistent memory, also run correctly in a system with causal memory. That is,

> **DRF theorem:** If program $\Pi$ is data-race free, then all histories of $\Pi$ when run on causal memory are sequentially consistent.

For completeness, the definition of data-race free is given as follows. For more details and discussions, you can refer to [“Data-race free” programs at cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22158/4911).

> **DRF:** Program $\Pi$ is data-race free if, for all histories $H$ of $\Pi$ and all causality orders $\leadsto$ of $H$, if $H$ has a serialization that respects $\leadsto$ (note that this implies that $H$ is sequentially consistent), then $H$ is data-race free with respect to $\leadsto$.

This theorem is important and beneficial to programmers because data-race free programs can be written *assuming* a sequentially consistent memory even for a system that provides causal memory.

Despite such "equivalence" DRF theorem, I am still curious about the detailed behaviors of data-race free programs when run on causal memory and on sequentially consistent memory. Formally,

> **My problem:** Let $\Pi$ be a data-race free program. When run on causal memory, $\Pi$ results in a set (denoted $E_{c}$) of (possibly infinite many) executions. When run on sequentially consistent memory, it results in a set (denoted $E_{s}$) of (possibly infinite many) executions. Though, according to DRF theorem, every execution in $E_{c}$ is sequentially consistent, are the two sets of executions *equal*, i.e., $E_c = E_s$?

This problem is essentially inspired by the paper ["Linearizable Implementations Do Not Suﬃce for Randomized Distributed Computation" (arXiv for STOC'2011)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4690v2.pdf), which shows that linearizability does not suffice for randomized algorithms. Specifically, using well-known linearizable *implementations* of objects in place of atomic objects can change the probability distribution of the executions (and thus the outcomes).

I want to investigate whether such phenomenon happens in the context of data-race free programs on different memory models. Here the data-race free programs may be deterministic or randomized which permit local coin-flips.